# how can I configure google cloud storage?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

**I have to use google cloud storage but to configure it I must enable billing.
does anyone know how I can avoid enable billing ???
can i use google cloud with enable billing??**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a billing question that'd be best directed at the vendor.

Answer (score 2):

Since GAE 1.9.0. you can use a default bucket with free cloudstorage quota.

I use Python. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133) with more information about the default bucket and free quota.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Storage costs money, so no, there's no magic way to get it for free.

Comment: but can I use my personal space( 15 GB) with google account to store data from android application? @ceejayoz

Comment: @user3501541 That's Google Drive, not Google Cloud Storage.