# GAE + Android + Blobstore = Video streaming solutions?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, video, youtube

I have developed an Android app that stores MTB Tracks (GPX files) + Pictures + Comments in Google AppEngine.

My current setup is :

- Front end : Android app.
- Back end : Java AppEngine with Restlet and DataStore+BlobStore storing.
- 3 users.
- Completely free solution (I would like to keep it this way if possible).

When a user wants to see the pictures of a track, the pictures are downloaded from the BlobStore. The waiting time is acceptable.

Now I want to add Video support (GoPro vids), so I am searching for a technical solution :

1/ BlobStore (my best choice if it's possible) :

- Is there a way to store the videos in the BlobStore and provide streaming to an android device ? I haven't found positive answers yet.
- The BlobStore API calls are limited in time. You can serve parts of a Blob but can you use that to handle the Video streaming on the android device ?
- There is the GAE "Channel API" that provide a permanent connection but can you provide video stream via that channel ?

2/ Youtube :

- I can store the videos in Youtube via the Youtube Android API and keep the links of the vids in appengine. I would prefer it to be private and don't want to force users to have a Google+ account (i think it's possible but i will have to check). I would have to give permission to all the app users.
- Streaming will be done via Youtube app.

3/ Google Drive :

- The app already supports Drive connection (to store GPX backups) so I could give app users the permission to upload/read/delete to a folder hosted on my Drive.
- Streaming will be done via Drive app.

4/ Other solutions ?

Thanks for your help.

Pierre.

Comment: Gcs might be interesting for this.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood hello, all of my apps components are "free" and I would like to keep it like that if it's possible. GCS is a paid solution (no free quotas like GAE) if I understand the docs correctly ?

Comment: Well, you should mention such constraints in your question. In any case, there is now a free allowance on the "default GCS" bucket.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882986/how-can-i-configure-google-cloud-storage/22883159#22883159

Comment: @PaulCollingwood you are right, thanks for the tip. There's a "Default GCS Bucket Stored Data" of 5Gb (it will be well enough). I could enable the bucket and store vids there but how will the streaming of the video be done in the android side ? Dedicated app ? Or programmatically ? I see a GcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel...

Comment: can't help you there I'm afraid. I'm Dart on the client side :) but however you were going to do it anyway is probably the answer, at some level.